# Ограничение количества цифр в строке

Tags: java

Имеется такое условие.

```
if (telNumber.matches("^\\d\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{6}")) return true;
```

Оно у меня выводит true на такую входную строку 0(501)234567.  Но может быть, что первая цифра до начала скобки может быть не одна а не сколько, но всего цифр в строке должно быть не больше 10. В скобках должно быть строго 3 цифры. Как составить выражение на ограничение количества цифр?

Comment: Ну так у вас уже ограничение стоит: `\d{3}` - 3 символа

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы всего в строке было 10 цифр, а в скобках только 3. То что в скобках 3 я это знаю. Как сделать, чтобы в строке было не больше 10?
Сделал сейчас вот такое, но нельзя в диапазоне указать количество символов в скобках 
"^(\\d?[(\\d)]?\\d){10}$"

Comment: Считаем: `\d` - 1 цифра, `\d{3}` - 3 цифры, `\d{6}` - 6 цифр. 1 + 3 + 6 =10. Всё сходится, учите математику для начальных классов.

Comment: Да это было решение в лоб. А если будет начинается с 2-х цифр или с 3-х?
^(\d+[(\d)]?\d){10}$. Вот как указать количество цифр в скобках?

Comment: Почему вы не можете посмотреть длину строки? Если она больше 12 символов, то вам не подходит. Никакая регулярка для этого не нужна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать следующее выражение `"^(?=\\d+\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d+).{12}$"`, использующее positive lookahead для проверки формата:

`(?=\d+\(\d{3}\)\d+)` - одна или несколько цифр до первой скобки, 3 цифры в скобках, одна или несколько цифр после скобок.

и затем проверка длины строки `.{12}` для контроля длины 12 = 10 цифр + 2 скобки:

```java
public static boolean isValidPhone(String phone) {
    return phone.matches("(?=\\d+\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d+).{12}");
}
```

[Онлайн демо](https://regex101.com/r/2KRKIe/1/)

---

Аналогично, можно сперва проверить длину строки *без регулярки*, а затем проверять формат:

```java
public static boolean isValidPhone(String phone) {
    return phone.length() == 12 && phone.matches("\\d+\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d+");
}
```